# curious simplification problem

Tags: programming, conditional

Consider the following expression:

```
If[x==x, 1, 2]
```

This returns 1, as you might guess. However:

```
If[x<x, 1, 2]
```

Returns unevaluated. Now, your fevered mind mind conceive of some domain where $<$ is not a total order, but rest easy:

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], If[x<x, 1, 2]]
```

exhibits the same behavior.

Question is, how can one deal with this?

Comment: `If` does not simplify. Adding `// Simplify` simplifies the expression in the way you'd expect.

Comment: Also, notice the documentation of `Equal`: "lhs==rhs returns `True` if lhs and rhs are ordinary identical expressions." while `x < x` does not auto-simplify. Furthermore, you may be interested in the optional fourth argument of `If` (see documentation).

Comment: @JEM_Mosig The `Simplify` solution is not wonderful, since you might have something like `If[x<x, horrible expression, 5]` `Simplify` would go away forever.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig As for the optional fourth arg, I hope you are joking.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig ... since `x<x1` is not exactly a deep mystery, and I would REALLY want to treat it as `False`.

Comment: `Assuming` has no effect here because `If` has no `Assumptions` option. In fact `If` tends more towards being a "programming function" and `<` towards being a construct for representing mathematical statements... the mixup and overlap between these two categories causes a lot of confusion about Mathematica. I believe the reason for `x>x` not having auto-simplification is exactly what you suspected: `x` may not, in general, be real-valued. Not only is auto-simplification missing, forced refinement also fails: `Refine[x>x]`. Unless we specify that `x` is real: `Refine[x > x, x \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: @Szabolcs precisely. These semantic issues have always been there, alas.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make the confusion complete:

```
c = 0;
x := ++c;
If[x == x, 1, 2]
If[x < x, 1, 2]
x \[Element] Reals
(* 2 *)
(* 1 *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: I think this actually makes sense, from a sequential evaluation perspective. And it explains the OP's confusion too.

Comment: @b3m2a1 This was actually my point...

Comment: Ah I read "make the confusion complete" as "to further enhance the confusion".

Comment: @b3m2a1 You know, that's just a saying here where I live...

Comment: That's a nice example, which brings up the real point of what a mess Mathematica semantics is (now all of us can generally steer clear of the pitfalls, but it requires discipline).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it, e.g. by introducing a new function `RealQ` and by specifying

```
Unprotect[Less];
x_?RealQ < x_?RealQ := False
Protect[Less];
```

For the symbol `x`, you can tell Mathematica that `x` is meant to be a real number this way:

```
RealQ[x] = True;
```

Now, you obtain
    x < x
    If[x < x, 1, 2]

```
(* False *)
(* 2 *)
```